# how to use a MySql database within Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, mysql-connector

I am very new to programming, so please bear with me, and apologies in advance if at first I dont make sense...!

I am doing an undergrad programming project, and need to make some databases within a Java program.  I am using eclipse (galilo) to write my program.  I have downloaded a connector/J, but havent the foggiest how i should use it!

Anyone out there able to give me a step by step approach?!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a data explorer of some sort inside your eclipse, you can look at the links provided above or more specifically the plugin's documentation.

OTOH, if you want to know how you connect to a mysql database using JDBC, the below code sample explains it.

```
Connection connection = null;
        try {
            //Loading the JDBC driver for MySql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Getting a connection to the database. Change the URL parameters
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Server/Schema", "username", "password");

            //Creating a statement object
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            //Executing the query and getting the result set
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from item");

            //Iterating the resultset and printing the 3rd column
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            }
            //close the resultset, statement and connection.
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,91363,91363

http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2009/08/setup-mysql-development-in-eclipse.html

http://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2006/spring/10200-1/mysql/JDBC.pdf