# How to configure mySQL on Eclipse EE (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Downloaded:

Java EE

Eclipse Indigo EE

mySQL 5.5

From this point I have no idea about how to create a mySQL database directly from eclipse. I've found methods which employ WAMP servers, however I'm not aiming to do it that way.
I believe that the first step lies in somehow configuring mySQL with eclipse/java, but I'm kind of lost at this point, I have no idea on how to proceed.

Note: Given that I'm a beginner to this field of CS, my question might lack necessary details, thus if you feel that way then please let me know, I'll edit my question with more details.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If more help needed, here's a pictuto that's very clear and goes step by step :

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Setup_MySQL_DB_in_Eclipse

Comment: Hey thanks for the useful link. I followed all the steps, everything went perfect till the last step. When I clicked on 'test connection' I got a pop up box which said 'ping failed' Any idea about how to get around this issue?

Comment: I hope you didn't forget to install mysql with wamp or whatever :D, apart from that make sure your mysql server is running and also make sure the credentials you used in configuring datasource in eclipse are same used in your mysql instance. pay attention to ports conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following links :

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,91363,91363

http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2009/08/setup-mysql-development-in-eclipse.html

http://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2006/spring/10200-1/mysql/JDBC.pdf

From here : 
[how to use a MySql database within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457179/how-to-use-a-mysql-database-within-eclipse) (Specifically **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457188/325742)** answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for eclipse. Works with all oracle/mysql/postgre.
No need of external ide like SQLyog for db operations/queries...﻿

[click here to get Toad Plugin for eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/toad-extension-eclipse#.UqhSMvRpkcx)