# Installing MySql on mac and the connectivity between MySql and eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, osx-elcapitan

Can some one give me instructions to install mysql on mac and the connectivity between eclipse and the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

[Download MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)

[Read the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html)

[More info on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853464/how-to-configure-mysql-on-eclipse-ee-java)

---

If you have an actual issue you can [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)